# A language $\mathcal{L}$ with $n$ atomic propositions can express $2^{2^n}$ non-equivalent propositions

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I tried to prove the statement and wasn't sure if it is correct.

### Theorem

A language $\mathcal{L}$ with $n$ atomic propositions can express $2^{2^n}$ non-equivalent propositions.

### **Proof**

Two propositions $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $\mathcal{L}$ are logically equivalent if and only if $\alpha[\epsilon_0,\ldots,\epsilon_n]=\beta[\epsilon_0,\ldots,\epsilon_n]$ for all $\epsilon_0,\ldots,\epsilon_n\in\{0,1\}$, if $\alpha$ and $\beta$ define the identical $n$-ary
truth function.

Since there is for every truth function $h$ a proposition $\varphi\in\mathcal{L}$ that defines $h$, it follows that the number of pairwise non-equivalent propositions in $\mathcal{L}$ is equal to the number of truth functions $h:\{0,1\}^n\rightarrow\{0,1\}$.

Now consider the truth functions $h:\{0,1\}^{n}\rightarrow\{0,1\}$. Since there are $2^{n}$ elements in $\{0,1\}^{n}$ and each argument is mapped to one of the two elements of $\{0,1\}$, there are $\underbrace{2\times2\times\cdots\times2}_{2^{n} \text{ times}}=2^{2^{n}}$ different truth functions $h$, as required.

Answer (score 3):

It's **not** true that $2^{2(n+1)}=2^{2^{n+1}}$. Remember that exponentiation is non-associative: "$a^{b^c}$" means "$a^{(b^c)}$," not "$(a^b)^c$." For example, $$2^{2^3}=2^{(2^3)}=2^8=256\color{red}{\not=}64=2^6=(2^2)^3.$$ In fact, you're thinking too narrowly about how propositions can be "combined." Try showing that with three atomic propositions $P,Q,R$ you can express **more** than $64$ different things.

*(HINT: think combinatorially. The simpler function $2^n$ counts the number of subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$, or equivalently the number of truth assignments on $n$ propositional atoms. $2^{2^n}$ counts the number of **sets of** truth assignments on $n$ propositional atoms; do you see how to identify a possibly-non-atomic proposition with a set of truth assignments?)*

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and sorry for the embarrassing mistake. Wouldn't it be easier to show that there are $2^{2^n}$ different truth functions $h: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}$ and to use the fact that there is for each truth function a proposition defining it?

Comment: @pahohu I'm not sure I see the difference between that and my answer, really, but sure - whichever's more intuitive!

Comment: Oh sorry, then I certainly didn't get you right. I just edited my proof above. Would this suffice?